A strange over-append by the function
In this section of homework, we are asked to write a function ctx_append (abbreviation of context append, I guess), which should operate like this:
Before:     ctx_k: { "a", "b", "" }
            ctx_v: { 42,  43 }

Operation:  ctx_append("c", 44, ctx_k, ctx_v, 20);

After:      ctx_k: { "a", "b", "c", "" }
            ctx_v: { 42,  43,  44 }

The following represents an empty context:
ctx_k: { "" }
ctx_v: { }

The program should use a helper function ctx_append_impl that has to operate in a recursive approach.
The following is my work:
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "interpreter.h" //the only use of this header file in the following functions is 
                         //provide the definition of MAX_INDENT_LEN

#include "raise.h" //the only use of this header file is provide the definition of raise() and
                   //ctx_overflow

using namespace std;



int find_empty_string(char ctx_k[][MAX_IDENT_LEN], unsigned int idx){

    //since the ctx_k ends with "", we have to use this function to locate where shall we append the content in the char array ident[]
    //MAX_INDENT_LEN = 64

    if (ctx_k[idx][0] == '"' && ctx_k[idx][1] == '"'){ //find the empty string
        return idx;
    }
    else{
        find_empty_string(ctx_k, idx + 1);
    }
}

int find_zero_val(int ctx_v[], unsigned int idx){

    //since the ctx_v ends with 0, we have to use this function to locate where shall we append the value in the int array val[]
    //MAX_INDENT_LEN = 64

    if (ctx_v[idx] == 0){
        return idx;
    }
    else{
        return find_zero_val(ctx_v, idx + 1);
    }
}

void ctx_append_impl(const char ident[], int val, char ctx_k[][MAX_IDENT_LEN], int ctx_v[], unsigned int size, unsigned int idx){ 

    // the function for appending the content inside ident[] to ctx_k and val to ctx_v
    // size is the max number of strings allowed to contain
    // idx is the current index of the ident
    // MAX_INDENT_LEN = 64

    int empty_string_position = find_empty_string(ctx_k, 0);
    cout<<"empty_string_position: "<<empty_string_position<<endl;
    int zero_val_position = find_zero_val(ctx_v, 0);
    cout<<"zero_val_position: "<<zero_val_position<<endl;

    if (idx>size){
        raise(ctx_overflow);
    }
    else if(idx==size || ident[idx] == '\0'){
        return;
    }
    
    else {
        ctx_append_impl(ident, val, ctx_k, ctx_v, size, idx+1);
        ctx_k[empty_string_position][idx] = ident[idx];
    }
    
    ctx_k[empty_string_position+1][0] = '"'; //closing string, step 1
    ctx_k[empty_string_position+1][1] = '"'; //closing string, step 2
    ctx_v[zero_val_position] = val; //update the value
    ctx_v[zero_val_position+1] = 0; //close the ctx_v array
    
}

void ctx_append(const char ident[], int val, char ctx_k[][MAX_IDENT_LEN], int ctx_v[], unsigned int size){
    ctx_append_impl(ident, val, ctx_k, ctx_v, size, 0);
}

int main(){
    char s[100][MAX_IDENT_LEN]={{'a', 'b','\0'}, {'"','"','\0'}};
    cout<<"s: "<<s[0][1]<<s[1][1]<<s[2][2]<<endl;
    const char t[]={'c'};
    int v[100] = {1, 2, };
    int a=3;
    
    ctx_append(t, a, s, v, 100);
    cout<<"new s: "<<s[0][0]<<s[0][1]<<s[1][0]<<s[1][1]<<endl;
    cout<<"new v: "<<v[0]<<v[1]<<v[2]<<v[3]<<endl;
}

The expected output of "new s" should be abc   only, but when I compile and run it, the ourput become abca, where I have no idea where the last "a" appears.
Initially I suspect that the bug was due to the absence of '\0' in const char t[], so I edited t[] toconst char t[]={'c', '\0'}
But the bug still occurs, the only change is that the output is abc" now.

Do you have warnings turned on? If not, you should and find out that the compiler is screaming about find_empty_string not returning on all paths. This code is also simple enough that you can through it in a debugger and fine out where things are going wrong.

If you compare find_empty_string to find_zero_val, you will see that you forgot something.

It is also unclear what the recursive process in ctx_append_impl is supposed to accomplish. There are two cases that terminate and one that just recurses infinitely without doing any useful work. Presumably the intent by your teacher was that ctx_append_impl should check if if ctx_k[idx] was "the empty string" and otherwise recur on idx+1. Are you sure "the empty string" is supposed to be represented by two " characters and not a single NUL byte?

Yes the empty string is supposed to be represented by two  ' " ' characters. And our instructor only mentioned that we should implement 'ctx_append_impl' recursively and 'ctx_append' should call for 'ctx_append_impl'.

Are you allowed to change the function signature of ctx_append_impl? If you can add two flags to see if the zero value and the empty string have been seen, this becomes a lot simpler.

No we are not allowed...

If the signature is identical to ctx_append there is no point in having a distinct helper function. Check the assignment again.

Did your instructor provide the main in your example? They seem to be teaching "C with std::cout" instead of C++

So the problem occured because initially there are a '"' in ctx_k[1][1] and I forgot to deal with it... the problem was solved after I inserted the following code 'ctx_k[empty_string_position][idx] = '\0';' between     else if(idx==size || ident[idx] == '\0'){return}
Thanks for all you guys that helped me to debug!
